# Double last character of each list of strings using python

Tags: python, list

I have this list:

```
list1 = ["happy","sad","love","bad"]
```

and I want to duplicate last character of each word, it should be like this:

```
list2 = ["happyy","sadd","lovee","badd"]
```

I tried this:

```
list1 = ["happy","sad","love","bad"]
l = len(list1)-1
ls = len(list1[l])-1
list2 = []
k=0
i=0
for k in list1[l]:
   for i in list1[ls]:
       list2.append(list1[l]+list1[ls-1])
print(list2)
```

I got this:

> ['badsad', 'badsad', 'badsad', 'badsad', 'badsad', 'badsad', 'badsad', 'badsad', 'badsad', 'badsad', 'badsad', 'badsad']

Comment: Have you tried anything, show your code??

Comment: @Hackaholic Yea I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension. `s[-1]` will give you the last character of a string `s`, if it has any characters. So you should make sure not to index into the empty string.

```
>>> list1 = ["happy","sad","love","bad",'']
>>> [s + s[-1] if s else s for s in list1]
['happyy', 'sadd', 'lovee', 'badd', '']
```

Alternative:

```
>>> [s + s[len(s)-1:] for s in list1]
['happyy', 'sadd', 'lovee', 'badd', '']
```

I think the second one is a little better to read.

Edit: actually, I like this one much better, I don't how it eluded me:

```
>>> list1 = ["happy","sad","love","bad",'']
>>> [s + s[-1:] for s in list1]
['happyy', 'sadd', 'lovee', 'badd', '']
```

Comment: what about if I want this list: list2=["happy sad","sad love","love bad"]

Comment: @Ahmed `[' '.join(x) for x in zip(lst, lst[1:])]`

Comment: smart answer I did it like this :
`l=[]
i=0
while i<len(list1)-1:
    k = list1[i]+" "+list1[i+1]
    l.append(k)
    i+=1
print(l)`

Answer (score 2):

In Python you can use slicing to do this.

```
list1 = ["happy","sad","love","bad"]
list2 = []
for l in list1:
    list2.append(l+l[-1])

print(list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

To simply repeat the last character, use index value of `-1` and append it to the string.

```
>>> i = "happy"
>>> i[-1]
'y'
>>> i + i[-1]
'happyy'
```

You don't need to iterate over the list *twice*. Use one `for` loop and take each element, modify the string like shown above and then append it to the new list.

A shorter way of doing it would be to use list comprehension. I'll let you figure that one on your own. :)

Comment: you must not directly post your answer, dont do spoon feeding, here OP haven't shown any effort of solving question.
Stackoverflow is not for spoon feeding

Comment: @Hackaholic calm down bro

Comment: I am chill brother, but i am just saying, if we directly post answer, other will not get chance to learn

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter bit of code that does what you're looking for (using Python 3.3):

```
myList = ["happy","sad","love","bad"]
for i in range(len(myList)):        
    myList[i] = myList[i]+myList[i][-1]
print myList
```

The trick to this is using [-1] to index a string starting from the right. So `"happy"[-1] = "y".` Then I concatenated the original string with the last letter of the same string to produce your result. Of course, there are many, many other (and better) ways to accomplish this, but this is what immediately popped into my head. Hope it helps!

Also note that this alters the original list your strings are in, so you'll have to alter this to store the new strings in a second list.

Answer (score 1):

Given your code:

```
list1 = ["happy","sad","love","bad"]
l = len(list1)-1
ls = len(list1[l])-1
```

`l` and `ls` are indexes for list, not strings inside the list. Thus what you got were like `sadbad`. Loop through the list to gain each string:

```
for s in list1:
    print s, s[-1] # s[-1] is the last char of str

>> happy y
>> sad d
...
```

And manipulate on each string:

```
list2 = [] # final result 
for s in list1:
    ss = s + s[-1] # concatenate the last character
    list2.append(ss)
```

`list2` will be what you need.

Of course, list comprehension will be useful:

```
# single line that equivalent to above four lines
list2 = [s+s[-1] for s in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to assign counter for a list1 let's say x
the last letter of each will would be x[-1]
if we need to print the list again we need to set up a loop

```
list2 = [x + x[-1] for x in list1]
print(list2)
```